# Serialization of String in C Bug

Tags: c

There is a problem with the serialization of string in C. Compiler does not correctly accept format type, even with type equivalence:

```
unsigned int voltage = 24;
unsigned int cfac = 23;
char buf[100];
sprintf("echo Voltage: %u, Cfac: %u > v.txt", voltage, cfac);
system(buf);
```

However, compiler is incorrectly interpreting unsigned integer as pointer:

error: invalid conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'const char*'

I double check that %u is unsigned int and not const char * however this compiler will not resolve. Can someone explain me why this GNU compiler is so crappy this codes work in Visual Studio I know for a fact.

Regards
Pradeep

Comment: Even if that were to compile with Visual Studio's C/C++ compiler, you'd get an access violation at run-time.  So no, this code does not "work" in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes but at least it compiles. With GNU it does not even compile which shows me that free software is low quality compared to microsoft

Comment: "It compiles" is NOT A GOOD THING when the code is wrong.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the code is wrong, a working program with a bug is better than a program that doesn't even working

Comment: With that attitude, just comment out every line where you get an error.  Iteratively until it compiles.  How bad can passing absolute garbage to `system()` be?

Comment: At least read about how to use [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: Yes I understand but my point is that it is better to have a car that turns on that has a problem then a car that does not turn on at all. Surely everyone can agree

Answer (score 4):

The first parameter to `sprintf()` is `buf`, not the format string.

Also, don't use `sprintf()` as it could cause a buffer overflow, use `snprintf()` or the equivalent instead,

```
int length;
length = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "echo Voltage: %u, Cfac: %u > v.txt", voltage, cfac);
if ((length != -1) && (length < sizeof buf)) {
    system(buf);
}
```

Finally, using `system()` to execute `echo` is very pointless.

Because your code apparently is equivalent to

```
FILE *file = fopen("v.txt", "w");
if (file != NULL) {
    fprintf(file, "Voltage: %u, Cfac: %u", voltage, cfac);
    fclose(file);
}
```

If you will invoke the shell, you should do so with the output of your program, and not from within your program. Read about the unix philosophy, though not perfect, they really know about this, and the unix way is THE way.

Comment: system() is to write the string to a file